# Largest shingle matching in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Given a corpus of, say, restaurant names like *ocean club*, I'd like to match queries / partial sentences against this corpus so that the query matches when one of it's shingles (token ngrams) matches.

Ideally it should start finding the largest shingle first and move to smaller shingles when no result is found. If a result is found, the search should stop and the result should be returned.

As an example,let's say I want to match *the ocean club restaurant* against *ocean club*.

1. It would first try to match the entire query (4-shingle) `no match`.
2. Then try all 2 3-shingle `no match`
3. then try all 3 2-shingle. `match on *ocean club*`
4. stop since match found.

Is this possible with Elasticsearch out-of-the-box?

If not, could this be done in some sort of custom ES-side analyzer? The naive way would be doing a lot of requests (1 for each shingle), which would likely be undoable in terms of performance.

Comment: What's the use case for this? Why do you want it done like this?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Goal is to get zero or one result in most cases. Requiring this high precision seems to disqualify just searching and checking on score/confidence (?) Pointers appreciated though. Might be making this more difficult than it is.

Comment: I think my <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215000/how-to-boost-indices-query-inside-a-boolean-query">question</a> should help you for the query and the analyzer.

Comment: @Geert-Jan if you sort by score (the default) and just get the first result only, is this not enough?

Comment: @AndreiStefan it might come close indeed. Let me just try that first. Thanks